# Accessibility: UISlider's UIControlEventValueChanged is not posted when slider.value is set in Voice-over mode

Tags: ios, accessibility, uislider

I am having a UISlider in my parent view. 
I want to honor the Voice-over gestures for slider movement and thus, i have implemented accessibilityIncrement and accessibilityDecrement methods as below:

```
- (void)accessibilityIncrement
{
     float finalValue = self.value;
    finalValue = (finalValue + 1);
    if (finalValue > self.maximumValue)
        finalValue = self.maximumValue;
    self.value = finalValue;    
}

- (void)accessibilityDecrement
{
    float finalValue = self.value;
    finalValue = (finalValue - 1);
    if (finalValue < self.minimumValue)
        finalValue = self.minimumValue;
    self.value = finalValue;

}
```

The issue is when I set the value of the slider (using self.value = finalValue), the selector for UIControlEventValueChanged event does not get called. Is this a Bug?

Thanks!

Comment: Figured out a work-around with the help of a friend, [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]; can be used inside accessibilityIncrement and accessibilityDecrement functions to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

A [recommended solution](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#continuous-adjustable-values) for a `UISlider` with VoiceOver consists in **using a delegate** in your code with the `increment` and `decrement` methods you already use to adapt the slider value according to the knob location.